# blank white page when post/update/change option etc

Tags: php, functions, themes

regards ,
i have a problem in theme i make it after test the theme on localhost i tried it on a host : when i try post , update , change option i got blank white page

then i enabled Debugging mode it gives me those errors

```
Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the 
arguments array for the "footer" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-1". 
Manually set the id to "sidebar-1" to silence this notice and keep existing 
sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. 
(This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in 
/home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4139

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/ar4web/functions.php:1) in 
/home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/ar4web/plugins/rf/ReduxCore/inc/class.redux_functions.php on 
line 56

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/ar4web/functions.php:1) in 
/home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php on line 197

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/ar4web/functions.php:1) in 
/home/ar4web/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210
```

i dont even know what i must edit in my funcotions.php

my functions php is :

```
 <?
        /* Start Footer Widget */
 register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'footer',
'before_widget' => '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-col">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<div class="logofooter">',
'after_title' => '</div><ul class="footer-ul">',
 ) );

                /* End Footer Widget */

                /* Start Post Thumbnails */

 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

 if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 352, true );
 }

                    /* End Post Thumbnails */

                    /* Start Theme Panel */


  if ( !class_exists( 'ReduxFramework' ) && file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/plugins/rf/ReduxCore/framework.php' ) ) {
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/plugins/rf/ReduxCore/framework.php' );
 }
 if ( !isset( $redux_demo ) && file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 
 '/plugins/rf/sample/sample-config.php' ) ) {
 require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/plugins/rf/sample/barebones-
 config.php' );
  }
                        /* End Theme Panel */

                        /* Start Menu */

   function register_my_menu() {
   register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'الناف بار' ));
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

                    /* End Menu */

                    /* Start ACF  */
  // 1. customize ACF path
   add_filter('acf/settings/path', 'my_acf_settings_path');

   function my_acf_settings_path( $path ) {

    // update path
   $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/acf/';

    // return
    return $path;

    }


   // 2. customize ACF dir
  add_filter('acf/settings/dir', 'my_acf_settings_dir');

  function my_acf_settings_dir( $dir ) {

  // update path
  $dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/plugins/acf/';

    // return
  return $dir;

  }


  // 3. Hide ACF field group menu item
  add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');


  // 4. Include ACF
  include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/acf/acf.php' );
  include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/acf/panel.php' );
                            /* End ACF  */
  include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/lwm/plugin.php');
  ?>
```

Comment: i resolve the first error by adding an id to sidebar now the first Notice disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function to call the sidebar **"needs to be called"** and also requires  an `id` and should be in this format:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'your_custom_sidebar' );

function your_custom_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer Sidebar', 'your_theme_lang' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-sidebar',
        'description'   => __( 'Some description', 'your_theme_lang' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-col">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="logofooter">',
        'after_title'   => '</div><ul class="footer-ul">',
    ) );
}
```